# python 'double comprehension' list to dict

Tags: python

Given a data structure '*posts*' like the following, is there a pythonesque/dict comprehension/efficient way of creating a dict with each of the ids as keys to the posts:

```python
posts = [{"ids":[1,2],...}, {"ids":[5, 6, 7], ...},...]
want = {1: {"ids":[1,2],..}, 2:{"ids":[1,2],...}, 5: {"ids":[5,6,7],...}, 6:{"ids":[5,6,7],..}, ...}

# long way
d = {}
for post in posts:
    for id in post['ids']:
        d[id] = post

# one comprehension - dicts created and disposed on each loop
d = {}
for post in posts:
    d.update({id: post for id in post['ids']})
```

I would hope the following would work - but the top level doesn't see the bottom level post

```python
# ilegal: post not available 
d = {id: post for id in post['ids'] for post in posts}
```

Any ideas? I see cases like this frequently and the loop seems ugly

Comment: Your for-loops are round the wrong way in the last solution -  i.e. they should be in the same order as the first solution (top to bottom -> left to right).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
posts = [{"ids":[1,2]}, {"ids":[5, 6, 7]}]
result = {i:b for b in posts for i in b['ids']}
```

Output:

```
{1: {'ids': [1, 2]}, 2: {'ids': [1, 2]}, 5: {'ids': [5, 6, 7]}, 6: {'ids': [5, 6, 7]}, 7: {'ids': [5, 6, 7]}}
```

Comment: Thanks, thats cool, I was getting the inner and outer comprehensions mixed up - it seems counter intuitive to have the outer loop first.

Comment: I tried solve it too, but you are too fast :) great solution